# MOV src, dest (or) MOV dest, src?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, masm, gnu-assembler

MOV is probably the first instruction everyone learns while learning ASM.

Just now I encountered a book [Assembly Language Programming in GNU/Linux for IA32 Architectures By Rajat Moona](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=C3_WIQOYE2EC&lpg=PP1&dq=Assembly%20Language%20Programming%20in%20GNU%2FLinux%20for%20IA32%20Architectures&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=&f=false) which says: (broken link removed)

But I learnt that it is `MOV dest, src`. Its like "Load `dest` with `src`". Even [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_(x86_instruction)) says the same.

I'm not saying that the author is wrong. I know that he is right. But what am I missing here?

btw.. he is using GCC's `as` to assemble these instructions. But that shouldn't change the instruction syntax right?

Comment: I should have read the preface and 1st paragraph of 1st chapter. I skipped them. :(

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`mov dest, src` is called **[Intel syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info)**.  (e.g. `mov eax, 123`)

`mov src, dest` is called **[AT&T syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info)**.  (e.g. `mov $123, %eax`)

UNIX assemblers including the GNU assembler uses AT&T syntax, all other x86 assemblers I know of uses Intel syntax. You can read up on the differences [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax).

Comment: Some people just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: Note that GNU assembler uses AT&T syntax _by default_, not unconditionally. You can switch it to Intel syntax using `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive.

Comment: YASM has a gas syntax mode.  clang's built-in assembler is gas-compatible and only supports GAS directives, so I guess you'd consider it a "Unix" assembler even when it's running on Windows, @fuz.  Same for GAS on Windows, too, I guess?  They have their origins in Unix.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was thinking along the lines of “what the `as` binary accepts on UNIX systems.”

Comment: If I recall correctly there is some kind of command line switch, it might be `-Mintel` or something

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as/gas use AT&T syntax that uses the order src,dest. MASM, TASM, NASM, etc. all use the order 'dest, src". As it happens, AT&T syntax doesn't fit very well with Intel processors, and (at least IMO) is a nearly unreadable mess. E.g. `movzx` comes out particularly bad.

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct types of assembly language syntax - Intel and AT&T syntax.
You can find a comparison of both on [Wikipedia's assembly language page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_syntax#Syntax).

Chances are your book uses the AT&T syntax, where the source operand comes before the destination.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the answer by Jerry Coffin, the Intel syntax fits better with the encoding of instructions for the x86 architecture. As a comment in my debugger's disassembler states, "[the operands appear in the instruction in the same order as they appear in the disassembly output](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/16347342d7ba/source/uu.asm#l401)". For example, consider this instruction:

```
-a
1772:0100 test word [AA55], 1234
1772:0106
-u 100 l 1
1772:0100 F70655AA3412      test    word [AA55], 1234
-
```

As you can read in the opcode hexdump, the instruction opcode `0F7h` is first, then the ModR/M byte `06h`, then the little-endian offset word `0AA55h`, and then finally the immediate word `1234h`. The Intel syntax matches that order in the assembly source. In the AT&T syntax this would look like `testw $0x1234, (0xAA55)` which swaps the order compared to the encoding.

Another example that obeys the Intel syntax order is comparison conditions. For example, consider this sequence:

```
cmp ax, 26
jae .label
```

This will jump to `.label` if `ax` **is above-or-equal-to** 26 (in unsigned comparison). This mnemonic is only true of the `cmp dest, src` operand order, which sets flags as for `dest -= src`.

Comment: the more important thing is that Intel syntax matches everything in Intel and AMD's manual, whereas with the AT&T syntax you'll have trouble finding many instructions like movsbl...

Comment: @phuclv: There are (and **can be**) references and such involving the AT&T syntax too. But my point is that the machine code encoding fits only Intel syntax, so there's an objective reason to prefer it. The fact that most material uses Intel syntax is true too, but is incidental.