# implement 64-bit arithmetic on a 32-bit machine

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bigint

The following code computes the product of x and y and stores the result in memory. Data
type ll_t is defined to be equivalent to long long.

```
typedef long long ll_t;
void store_prod(ll_t *dest, int x, ll_t y) {
    *dest = x*y;
}
```

gcc generates the following assembly code implementing the computation:
dest at %ebp+8, x at %ebp+12, y at %ebp+16

```
1 movl 16(%ebp), %esi
2 movl 12(%ebp), %eax
3 movl %eax, %edx
4 sarl $31, %edx
5 movl 20(%ebp), %ecx
6 imull %eax, %ecx
7 movl %edx, %ebx
8 imull %esi, %ebx
9 addl %ebx, %ecx
10 mull %esi
11 leal (%ecx,%edx), %edx
12 movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
13 movl %eax, (%ecx)
14 movl %edx, 4(%ecx)
```

This code uses three multiplications to implement the multiprecision arithmetic
required to implement 64-bit arithmetic on a 32-bit machine. Describe the
algorithm used to compute the product, and annotate the assembly code to show
how it realizes your algorithm.

***I don't understand line 8 and line 9 in assembly code above. Can anyone help?***

Comment: Seems like it's doing something very tricky to not need add-with-carry instructions...

Comment: @Mysticial Nothing tricky. You don't need ADC when computing truncated products as is the case here.

Comment: Standard SO response: what have you tried? From your comment below, what you're really asking is: what is the algorithm. Well, that's your homework; that's what you're supposed to figure out. What have you done so far in your attempts to figure it out? You say you know what the instructions do ... then perhaps start by writing that down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've converted it to intel syntax.

```
mov esi, y_low
mov eax, x
mov edx, eax
sar edx, 31
mov ecx, y_high

imul ecx, eax ; ecx = y_high *{signed} x

mov ebx, edx

imul ebx, esi ; ebx = sign_extension(x) *{signed} y_low

add ecx, ebx ; ecx = y_high *{signed} x_low + x_high *{signed} y_low

mul esi ; edx:eax = x_low *{unsigned} y_low

lea edx, [ecx + edx] ; edx = high(x_low *{unsigned} y_low + y_high *{signed} x_low + x_high *{signed} y_low)

mov ecx, dest
mov [ecx], eax
mov [ecx + 4], edx
```

What the above code does is multiplication of 2 64-bit signed integers that keeps the least-significant 64 bits of the product.

Where does the other 64-bit multiplicand come from? It's `x` *sign-extended* from 32 bits to 64. The `sar` instruction is used to replicate `x's` sign bit into all bits of `edx`. I call this value consisting only of the `x's` sign `x_high`. `x_low` is the value of `x` actually passed into the routine.

`y_low` and `y_high` are the least and most significant parts of `y`, just like `x's` `x_low` and `x_high` are.

From here it's pretty easy:

product = `y` *{signed} `x` =
(`y_high` * 2<sup>32</sup> + `y_low`) *{signed} (`x_high` * 2<sup>32</sup> + `x_low`) =
`y_high` *{signed} `x_high` * 2<sup>64</sup> +
`y_high` *{signed} `x_low` * 2<sup>32</sup> +
`y_low` *{signed} `x_high` * 2<sup>32</sup> +
`y_low` *{signed} `x_low`

`y_high` *{signed} `x_high` * 2<sup>64</sup> isn't calculated because it doesn't contribute to the least significant 64 bits of the product. We'd calculate it if we were interested in the full 128-bit product (full 96-bit product for the picky).

`y_low` *{signed} `x_low` is calculated using unsigned multiplication. It's legal to do so because 2's complement signed multiplication gives the same least significant bits as unsigned multiplication. Example:
-1 *{signed} -1 = 1
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF *{unsigned} 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0000000000000001 (64 least significant bits are equivalent to 1)

Comment: Excellent answer, but probably too detailed for a `homework` tag - speaking from a TA perspective here.

Comment: thank you very much, I see what happened. The algorithm I thought                           was  x * (y_high * 2^32 + y_low)(x is 32 bit ), that's why I was confused about line 8 and line 9. I wonder is it necessary to extend x to 64 bit.

Comment: I figured out why should x be extended to 64 bit.

Comment: `cdq` is equivalent to `mov edx, eax` / `sar edx,31` - it sign-extends EAX into EDX:EAX.  `lea edx, [ecx + edx]` might as well be `add edx, ecx`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the context of line 8 and 9.

By this time, `ESI` contains the lower half of `y` and `EBX` contains `sgn(x)`. So line 8 is just computing `sgn(x) * (y % 2^32)` and storing it in `EBX`.

Line 9 draws upon that result. By the time Line 9 happens, `ECX` contains a partial upper half of the multiplication, that is, `x * (y >> 32)` signed. So `EBX+ECX` ends up being what we computed in the last step plus the partial upper half we found on a previous line.

The full algorithm itself is pretty neat ;)

EDIT: In response to a comment below...

Line 4: Consider what `SAR EDX, 31` (or if you like, `sar $31, %edx`) really means. Since `EDX` is a 32-bit register, you'll end up with one of two values. Which two? Consider what they mean in the context of signed arithmetic.

Line 7: `EDX` by this point contains something pretty useful for the following operations. I'm just moving it where it needs to go.

Comment: thank you, but I still didn't get it. why should sgn(x) * (y % 2^32) be added to ECX? I think imull %eax %ecx has done the upper half of the multiplication.

Comment: Good question. You're right that `IMUL %eax, %ecx` has taken care of the upper half of the multiplication, but `sgn(x) * (y % 2^32)` doesn't touch the upper half at all. Consider the mathematical bounds on `sgn(x)` and `foo % 2^32`. You might also consider that two-operation IMUL truncates its result to 32 bits, though I don't think that's _directly_ relevant for the step in question.

Comment: sgn(x) * (y % 2^32) doesn't touch the upper half at all, but its value is added to ecx where the upper half of multiplication is stored.

Comment: This is absolutely true; we need the combined value later in the algorithm, so at this moment, we use `ECX` as an intermediate value essentially because it's there and we don't need the raw upper half anymore.

Comment: @atomicinf I believe you mean "two-operand" there instead of "two-operation"

Comment: @harold That is in fact what I meant. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 0):

What imul does is multiplies the contents of eax with ecx and saves the lower 32 bits in eax and higher 32 bits in edx.

addl as far as I remember adds the two registers and saves it on the first one so in this case ebx. (I am not sure if it does anything else and the l after addl stands for long)

Comment: The right operand is the destination, so line 9 puts %ebx + %ecx in %ecx.

Comment: this [link](http://www.cs.umd.edu/users/meesh/webpages/cmsc311/links/handouts/ia32.pdf) gives in depth knowledge and considering it is an homework.

Comment: That document doesn't match gnu's assembly language ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397528/mov-src-dest-or-mov-dest-src

Comment: thank you for your answer. this code is form the book cs_app second edition(homework 3.55). I know what those assembly instructions mean, but I am confused by the algorithm. What are line 4,7,8,9 for?

Comment: Two-operand IMUL signed-multiplies the two operands and stores the result in the destination operand. You've just described one-operand `IMUL ECX`.

Comment: @user1556375 see my updated answer, but since this is homework, you'll need to connect the dots yourself.

Comment: @morsel.wang If you wanted to know what the algorithm is, you should have just said that. But that's your homework and what you're supposed to be figuring out. What have you done to try to figure it out *yourself*?