# In assembly, How can I square(multiply) the 5 byte signed integer?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have to do 5 byte signed Int square. For example, I made a 5 byte random signed interger, and then want to know square these random signed interger at assembly lang. In x86-32 and MASM assembler, They does not support over the 32bit. So I meet trouble that square of it. We can use Irvine32 library, and below pic is the Irvine32 library list.[Irvine32 library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4viaP.png)  Please help me how to square these random 5byte signed interger.

Maybe, I think 5byte divide into 4 byte and 1byte to square it. But I don't know how to do it.

I don't know the algorithm that made signed integer square

Comment: See the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24238871/547981) with the special case of `x = y`

Comment: @Jester Squaring 5 bytes integer is simpler than generic 64-bit multiplication. I prepared the answer but question is already closed. Voting for reopen.

Comment: Since the question is closed i'll give the hint here. First, square is always non-negative. Take absolue value of argument and use unsigned multiplication. Second, 5-byte integer may be represented as two integers: `N = H*2³² + L`, where H and L are high and low parts respectively. Thus `N² = H²*2⁶⁴ + 2*2³²*H*L + L²`. Calculate `L*L`, store 64-bit result to memory. Calculate `H*L`, then multiply by 2 (probably using shift) and add low 32-bit word to millde 32-bit word of stored result, add carry to high bits and store to result. Calculate `H*H` and add 16 bits to high 16-bit word of result.

Comment: @dimich: Good point about needing to take the absolute value if you want a 10-byte full product.  The low x high cross product then need to be widening unsigned x signed, and there's no instruction to do that, only `mul` and `imul`.  We can sign-extend H to 32-bit instead of zero-extend like in their previous almost-identical question about unsigned, but the high half of the product would be wrong if L had it's MSB set.

Comment: The duplicate @Jester linked does non-widening 64x64 => 64-bit multiply, so for that you would just sign-extend H to 32-bit.  The OP hasn't specified what width of result they want, so dimich's full version might not be needed.  (It's also an unusual input size; makes me wonder if it's really a 40-bit integer or a 5-decimal-digit number stored in 5 ASCII bytes of input.  Especially since they're using Irvine32 which only has I/O helper functions for 32-bit integers, I think.)

Comment: @PeterCordes We don't need unsigned x signed. Assuming 5-byte argument is two's complement, entire value is negative if `H` is negative. Extend `H` to signed 32-bit value, then `neg low_part; adc high_part,0; neg high_part`. This will negate the argument and it may be multiplied by itself as unsigned.

Comment: @dimich: I meant if you were going to do it *without* conditionally negating to take the absolute value first.  If you don't need a widening multiply, you don't need to abs().  But if you do, then yes, abs() before squaring is presumably more efficient than emulating unsigned x signed multiply.