# Why does execution time change depending on the data type?

Tags: c, performance, time, types, execution

Why does the execution time changes when I use different data types in C?

Here is my first program in which I used `long long int` & got 4.61s execution time on codechef for a no. of test cases.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
long long int prm[] = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627,1637,1657,1663,1667,1669,1693,1697,1699,1709,1721,1723,1733,1741,1747,1753,1759,1777,1783,1787,1789,1801,1811,1823,1831,1847,1861,1867,1871,1873,1877,1879,1889,1901,1907,1913,1931,1933,1949,1951,1973,1979,1987,1993,1997,1999,2003,2011,2017,2027,2029,2039,2053,2063,2069,2081,2083,2087,2089,2099,2111,2113,2129,2131,2137,2141,2143,2153,2161,2179,2203,2207,2213,2221,2237,2239,2243,2251,2267,2269,2273,2281,2287,2293,2297,2309,2311,2333,2339,2341,2347,2351,2357,2371,2377,2381,2383,2389,2393,2399,2411,2417,2423,2437,2441,2447,2459,2467,2473,2477,2503,2521,2531,2539,2543,2549,2551,2557,2579,2591,2593,2609,2617,2621,2633,2647,2657,2659,2663,2671,2677,2683,2687,2689,2693,2699,2707,2711,2713,2719,2729,2731,2741,2749,2753,2767,2777,2789,2791,2797,2801,2803,2819,2833,2837,2843,2851,2857,2861,2879,2887,2897,2903,2909,2917,2927,2939,2953,2957,2963,2969,2971,2999,3001,3011,3019,3023,3037,3041,3049,3061,3067,3079,3083,3089,3109,3119,3121,3137,3163,3167,3169,3181,3187,3191,3203,3209,3217,3221,3229,3251,3253,3257,3259,3271,3299,3301,3307,3313,3319,3323,3329,3331,3343,3347,3359,3361,3371,3373,3389,3391,3407,3413,3433,3449,3457,3461,3463,3467,3469,3491,3499,3511,3517,3527,3529,3533,3539,3541,3547,3557,3559,3571,3581,3583,3593,3607,3613,3617,3623,3631,3637,3643,3659,3671,3673,3677,3691,3697,3701,3709,3719,3727,3733,3739,3761,3767,3769,3779,3793,3797,3803,3821,3823,3833,3847,3851,3853,3863,3877,3881,3889,3907,3911,3917,3919,3923,3929,3931,3943,3947,3967,3989,4001,4003,4007,4013,4019,4021,4027,4049,4051,4057,4073,4079,4091,4093,4099,4111,4127,4129,4133,4139,4153,4157,4159,4177,4201,4211,4217,4219,4229,4231,4241,4243,4253,4259,4261,4271,4273,4283,4289,4297,4327,4337,4339,4349,4357,4363,4373,4391,4397,4409,4421,4423,4441,4447,4451,4457,4463,4481,4483,4493,4507,4513,4517,4519,4523,4547,4549,4561,4567,4583,4591,4597,4603,4621,4637,4639,4643,4649,4651,4657,4663,4673,4679,4691,4703,4721,4723,4729,4733,4751,4759,4783,4787,4789,4793,4799,4801,4813,4817,4831,4861,4871,4877,4889,4903,4909,4919,4931,4933,4937,4943,4951,4957,4967,4969,4973,4987,4993,4999,5003,5009,5011,5021,5023,5039,5051,5059,5077,5081,5087,5099,5101,5107,5113,5119,5147,5153,5167,5171,5179,5189,5197,5209,5227,5231,5233,5237,5261,5273,5279,5281,5297,5303,5309,5323,5333,5347,5351,5381,5387,5393,5399,5407,5413,5417,5419,5431,5437,5441,5443,5449,5471,5477,5479,5483,5501,5503,5507,5519,5521,5527,5531,5557,5563,5569,5573,5581,5591,5623,5639,5641,5647,5651,5653,5657,5659,5669,5683,5689,5693,5701,5711,5717,5737,5741,5743,5749,5779,5783,5791,5801,5807,5813,5821,5827,5839,5843,5849,5851,5857,5861,5867,5869,5879,5881,5897,5903,5923,5927,5939,5953,5981,5987,6007,6011,6029,6037,6043,6047,6053,6067,6073,6079,6089,6091,6101,6113,6121,6131,6133,6143,6151,6163,6173,6197,6199,6203,6211,6217,6221,6229,6247,6257,6263,6269,6271,6277,6287,6299,6301,6311,6317,6323,6329,6337,6343,6353,6359,6361,6367,6373,6379,6389,6397,6421,6427,6449,6451,6469,6473,6481,6491,6521,6529,6547,6551,6553,6563,6569,6571,6577,6581,6599,6607,6619,6637,6653,6659,6661,6673,6679,6689,6691,6701,6703,6709,6719,6733,6737,6761,6763,6779,6781,6791,6793,6803,6823,6827,6829,6833,6841,6857,6863,6869,6871,6883,6899,6907,6911,6917,6947,6949,6959,6961,6967,6971,6977,6983,6991,6997,7001,7013,7019,7027,7039,7043,7057,7069,7079,7103,7109,7121,7127,7129,7151,7159,7177,7187,7193,7207,7211,7213,7219,7229,7237,7243,7247,7253,7283,7297,7307,7309,7321,7331,7333,7349,7351,7369,7393,7411,7417,7433,7451,7457,7459,7477,7481,7487,7489,7499,7507,7517,7523,7529,7537,7541,7547,7549,7559,7561,7573,7577,7583,7589,7591,7603,7607,7621,7639,7643,7649,7669,7673,7681,7687,7691,7699,7703,7717,7723,7727,7741,7753,7757,7759,7789,7793,7817,7823,7829,7841,7853,7867,7873,7877,7879,7883,7901,7907,7919,7927,7933,7937,7949,7951,7963,7993,8009,8011,8017,8039,8053,8059,8069,8081,8087,8089,8093,8101,8111,8117,8123,8147,8161,8167,8171,8179,8191,8209,8219,8221,8231,8233,8237,8243,8263,8269,8273,8287,8291,8293,8297,8311,8317,8329,8353,8363,8369,8377,8387,8389,8419,8423,8429,8431,8443,8447,8461,8467,8501,8513,8521,8527,8537,8539,8543,8563,8573,8581,8597,8599,8609,8623,8627,8629,8641,8647,8663,8669,8677,8681,8689,8693,8699,8707,8713,8719,8731,8737,8741,8747,8753,8761,8779,8783,8803,8807,8819,8821,8831,8837,8839,8849,8861,8863,8867,8887,8893,8923,8929,8933,8941,8951,8963,8969,8971,8999,9001,9007,9011,9013,9029,9041,9043,9049,9059,9067,9091,9103,9109,9127,9133,9137,9151,9157,9161,9173,9181,9187,9199,9203,9209,9221,9227,9239,9241,9257,9277,9281,9283,9293,9311,9319,9323,9337,9341,9343,9349,9371,9377,9391,9397,9403,9413,9419,9421,9431,9433,9437,9439,9461,9463,9467,9473,9479,9491,9497,9511,9521,9533,9539,9547,9551,9587,9601,9613,9619,9623,9629,9631,9643,9649,9661,9677,9679,9689,9697,9719,9721,9733,9739,9743,9749,9767,9769,9781,9787,9791,9803,9811,9817,9829,9833,9839,9851,9857,9859,9871,9883,9887,9901,9907,9923,9929,9931,9941,9949,9967,9973,10007,10009,10037,10039,10061,10067,10069,10079,10091,10093,10099,10103,10111,10133,10139,10141,10151,10159,10163,10169,10177,10181,10193,10211,10223,10243,10247,10253,10259,10267,10271,10273,10289,10301,10303,10313,10321,10331,10333,10337,10343,10357,10369,10391,10399,10427,10429,10433,10453,10457,10459,10463,10477,10487,10499,10501,10513,10529,10531,10559,10567,10589,10597,10601,10607,10613,10627,10631,10639,10651,10657,10663,10667,10687,10691,10709,10711,10723,10729,10733,10739,10753,10771,10781,10789,10799,10831,10837,10847,10853,10859,10861,10867,10883,10889,10891,10903,10909,10937,10939,10949,10957,10973,10979,10987,10993,11003,11027,11047,11057,11059,11069,11071,11083,11087,11093,11113,11117,11119,11131,11149,11159,11161,11171,11173,11177,11197,11213,11239,11243,11251,11257,11261,11273,11279,11287,11299,11311,11317,11321,11329,11351,11353,11369,11383,11393,11399,11411,11423,11437,11443,11447,11467,11471,11483,11489,11491,11497,11503,11519,11527,11549,11551,11579,11587,11593,11597,11617,11621,11633,11657,11677,11681,11689,11699,11701,11717,11719,11731,11743,11777,11779,11783,11789,11801,11807,11813,11821,11827,11831,11833,11839,11863,11867,11887,11897,11903,11909,11923,11927,11933,11939,11941,11953,11959,11969,11971,11981,11987,12007,12011,12037,12041,12043,12049,12071,12073,12097,12101,12107,12109,12113,12119,12143,12149,12157,12161,12163,12197,12203,12211,12227,12239,12241,12251,12253,12263,12269,12277,12281,12289,12301,12323,12329,12343,12347,12373,12377,12379,12391,12401,12409,12413,12421,12433,12437,12451,12457,12473,12479,12487,12491,12497,12503,12511,12517,12527,12539,12541,12547,12553,12569,12577,12583,12589,12601,12611,12613,12619,12637,12641,12647,12653,12659,12671,12689,12697,12703,12713,12721,12739,12743,12757,12763,12781,12791,12799,12809,12821,12823,12829,12841,12853,12889,12893,12899,12907,12911,12917,12919,12923,12941,12953,12959,12967,12973,12979,12983,13001,13003,13007,13009,13033,13037,13043,13049,13063,13093,13099,13103,13109,13121,13127,13147,13151,13159,13163,13171,13177,13183,13187,13217,13219,13229,13241,13249,13259,13267,13291,13297,13309,13313,13327,13331,13337,13339,13367,13381,13397,13399,13411,13417,13421,13441,13451,13457,13463,13469,13477,13487,13499,13513,13523,13537,13553,13567,13577,13591,13597,13613,13619,13627,13633,13649,13669,13679,13681,13687,13691,13693,13697,13709,13711,13721,13723,13729,13751,13757,13759,13763,13781,13789,13799,13807,13829,13831,13841,13859,13873,13877,13879,13883,13901,13903,13907,13913,13921,13931,13933,13963,13967,13997,13999,14009,14011,14029,14033,14051,14057,14071,14081,14083,14087,14107,14143,14149,14153,14159,14173,14177,14197,14207,14221,14243,14249,14251,14281,14293,14303,14321,14323,14327,14341,14347,14369,14387,14389,14401,14407,14411,14419,14423,14431,14437,14447,14449,14461,14479,14489,14503,14519,14533,14537,14543,14549,14551,14557,14561,14563,14591,14593,14621,14627,14629,14633,14639,14653,14657,14669,14683,14699,14713,14717,14723,14731,14737,14741,14747,14753,14759,14767,14771,14779,14783,14797,14813,14821,14827,14831,14843,14851,14867,14869,14879,14887,14891,14897,14923,14929,14939,14947,14951,14957,14969,14983,15013,15017,15031,15053,15061,15073,15077,15083,15091,15101,15107,15121,15131,15137,15139,15149,15161,15173,15187,15193,15199,15217,15227,15233,15241,15259,15263,15269,15271,15277,15287,15289,15299,15307,15313,15319,15329,15331,15349,15359,15361,15373,15377,15383,15391,15401,15413,15427,15439,15443,15451,15461,15467,15473,15493,15497,15511,15527,15541,15551,15559,15569,15581,15583,15601,15607,15619,15629,15641,15643,15647,15649,15661,15667,15671,15679,15683,15727,15731,15733,15737,15739,15749,15761,15767,15773,15787,15791,15797,15803,15809,15817,15823,15859,15877,15881,15887,15889,15901,15907,15913,15919,15923,15937,15959,15971,15973,15991,16001,16007,16033,16057,16061,16063,16067,16069,16073,16087,16091,16097,16103,16111,16127,16139,16141,16183,16187,16189,16193,16217,16223,16229,16231,16249,16253,16267,16273,16301,16319,16333,16339,16349,16361,16363,16369,16381,16411,16417,16421,16427,16433,16447,16451,16453,16477,16481,16487,16493,16519,16529,16547,16553,16561,16567,16573,16603,16607,16619,16631,16633,16649,16651,16657,16661,16673,16691,16693,16699,16703,16729,16741,16747,16759,16763,16787,16811,16823,16829,16831,16843,16871,16879,16883,16889,16901,16903,16921,16927,16931,16937,16943,16963,16979,16981,16987,16993,17011,17021,17027,17029,17033,17041,17047,17053,17077,17093,17099,17107,17117,17123,17137,17159,17167,17183,17189,17191,17203,17207,17209,17231,17239,17257,17291,17293,17299,17317,17321,17327,17333,17341,17351,17359,17377,17383,17387,17389,17393,17401,17417,17419,17431,17443,17449,17467,17471,17477,17483,17489,17491,17497,17509,17519,17539,17551,17569,17573,17579,17581,17597,17599,17609,17623,17627,17657,17659,17669,17681,17683,17707,17713,17729,17737,17747,17749,17761,17783,17789,17791,17807,17827,17837,17839,17851,17863,17881,17891,17903,17909,17911,17921,17923,17929,17939,17957,17959,17971,17977,17981,17987,17989,18013,18041,18043,18047,18049,18059,18061,18077,18089,18097,18119,18121,18127,18131,18133,18143,18149,18169,18181,18191,18199,18211,18217,18223,18229,18233,18251,18253,18257,18269,18287,18289,18301,18307,18311,18313,18329,18341,18353,18367,18371,18379,18397,18401,18413,18427,18433,18439,18443,18451,18457,18461,18481,18493,18503,18517,18521,18523,18539,18541,18553,18583,18587,18593,18617,18637,18661,18671,18679,18691,18701,18713,18719,18731,18743,18749,18757,18773,18787,18793,18797,18803,18839,18859,18869,18899,18911,18913,18917,18919,18947,18959,18973,18979,19001,19009,19013,19031,19037,19051,19069,19073,19079,19081,19087,19121,19139,19141,19157,19163,19181,19183,19207,19211,19213,19219,19231,19237,19249,19259,19267,19273,19289,19301,19309,19319,19333,19373,19379,19381,19387,19391,19403,19417,19421,19423,19427,19429,19433,19441,19447,19457,19463,19469,19471,19477,19483,19489,19501,19507,19531,19541,19543,19553,19559,19571,19577,19583,19597,19603,19609,19661,19681,19687,19697,19699,19709,19717,19727,19739,19751,19753,19759,19763,19777,19793,19801,19813,19819,19841,19843,19853,19861,19867,19889,19891,19913,19919,19927,19937,19949,19961,19963,19973,19979,19991,19993,19997,20011,20021,20023,20029,20047,20051,20063,20071,20089,20101,20107,20113,20117,20123,20129,20143,20147,20149,20161,20173,20177,20183,20201,20219,20231,20233,20249,20261,20269,20287,20297,20323,20327,20333,20341,20347,20353,20357,20359,20369,20389,20393,20399,20407,20411,20431,20441,20443,20477,20479,20483,20507,20509,20521,20533,20543,20549,20551,20563,20593,20599,20611,20627,20639,20641,20663,20681,20693,20707,20717,20719,20731,20743,20747,20749,20753,20759,20771,20773,20789,20807,20809,20849,20857,20873,20879,20887,20897,20899,20903,20921,20929,20939,20947,20959,20963,20981,20983,21001,21011,21013,21017,21019,21023,21031,21059,21061,21067,21089,21101,21107,21121,21139,21143,21149,21157,21163,21169,21179,21187,21191,21193,21211,21221,21227,21247,21269,21277,21283,21313,21317,21319,21323,21341,21347,21377,21379,21383,21391,21397,21401,21407,21419,21433,21467,21481,21487,21491,21493,21499,21503,21517,21521,21523,21529,21557,21559,21563,21569,21577,21587,21589,21599,21601,21611,21613,21617,21647,21649,21661,21673,21683,21701,21713,21727,21737,21739,21751,21757,21767,21773,21787,21799,21803,21817,21821,21839,21841,21851,21859,21863,21871,21881,21893,21911,21929,21937,21943,21961,21977,21991,21997,22003,22013,22027,22031,22037,22039,22051,22063,22067,22073,22079,22091,22093,22109,22111,22123,22129,22133,22147,22153,22157,22159,22171,22189,22193,22229,22247,22259,22271,22273,22277,22279,22283,22291,22303,22307,22343,22349,22367,22369,22381,22391,22397,22409,22433,22441,22447,22453,22469,22481,22483,22501,22511,22531,22541,22543,22549,22567,22571,22573,22613,22619,22621,22637,22639,22643,22651,22669,22679,22691,22697,22699,22709,22717,22721,22727,22739,22741,22751,22769,22777,22783,22787,22807,22811,22817,22853,22859,22861,22871,22877,22901,22907,22921,22937,22943,22961,22963,22973,22993,23003,23011,23017,23021,23027,23029,23039,23041,23053,23057,23059,23063,23071,23081,23087,23099,23117,23131,23143,23159,23167,23173,23189,23197,23201,23203,23209,23227,23251,23269,23279,23291,23293,23297,23311,23321,23327,23333,23339,23357,23369,23371,23399,23417,23431,23447,23459,23473,23497,23509,23531,23537,23539,23549,23557,23561,23563,23567,23581,23593,23599,23603,23609,23623,23627,23629,23633,23663,23669,23671,23677,23687,23689,23719,23741,23743,23747,23753,23761,23767,23773,23789,23801,23813,23819,23827,23831,23833,23857,23869,23873,23879,23887,23893,23899,23909,23911,23917,23929,23957,23971,23977,23981,23993,24001,24007,24019,24023,24029,24043,24049,24061,24071,24077,24083,24091,24097,24103,24107,24109,24113,24121,24133,24137,24151,24169,24179,24181,24197,24203,24223,24229,24239,24247,24251,24281,24317,24329,24337,24359,24371,24373,24379,24391,24407,24413,24419,24421,24439,24443,24469,24473,24481,24499,24509,24517,24527,24533,24547,24551,24571,24593,24611,24623,24631,24659,24671,24677,24683,24691,24697,24709,24733,24749,24763,24767,24781,24793,24799,24809,24821,24841,24847,24851,24859,24877,24889,24907,24917,24919,24923,24943,24953,24967,24971,24977,24979,24989,25013,25031,25033,25037,25057,25073,25087,25097,25111,25117,25121,25127,25147,25153,25163,25169,25171,25183,25189,25219,25229,25237,25243,25247,25253,25261,25301,25303,25307,25309,25321,25339,25343,25349,25357,25367,25373,25391,25409,25411,25423,25439,25447,25453,25457,25463,25469,25471,25523,25537,25541,25561,25577,25579,25583,25589,25601,25603,25609,25621,25633,25639,25643,25657,25667,25673,25679,25693,25703,25717,25733,25741,25747,25759,25763,25771,25793,25799,25801,25819,25841,25847,25849,25867,25873,25889,25903,25913,25919,25931,25933,25939,25943,25951,25969,25981,25997,25999,26003,26017,26021,26029,26041,26053,26083,26099,26107,26111,26113,26119,26141,26153,26161,26171,26177,26183,26189,26203,26209,26227,26237,26249,26251,26261,26263,26267,26293,26297,26309,26317,26321,26339,26347,26357,26371,26387,26393,26399,26407,26417,26423,26431,26437,26449,26459,26479,26489,26497,26501,26513,26539,26557,26561,26573,26591,26597,26627,26633,26641,26647,26669,26681,26683,26687,26693,26699,26701,26711,26713,26717,26723,26729,26731,26737,26759,26777,26783,26801,26813,26821,26833,26839,26849,26861,26863,26879,26881,26891,26893,26903,26921,26927,26947,26951,26953,26959,26981,26987,26993,27011,27017,27031,27043,27059,27061,27067,27073,27077,27091,27103,27107,27109,27127,27143,27179,27191,27197,27211,27239,27241,27253,27259,27271,27277,27281,27283,27299,27329,27337,27361,27367,27397,27407,27409,27427,27431,27437,27449,27457,27479,27481,27487,27509,27527,27529,27539,27541,27551,27581,27583,27611,27617,27631,27647,27653,27673,27689,27691,27697,27701,27733,27737,27739,27743,27749,27751,27763,27767,27773,27779,27791,27793,27799,27803,27809,27817,27823,27827,27847,27851,27883,27893,27901,27917,27919,27941,27943,27947,27953,27961,27967,27983,27997,28001,28019,28027,28031,28051,28057,28069,28081,28087,28097,28099,28109,28111,28123,28151,28163,28181,28183,28201,28211,28219,28229,28277,28279,28283,28289,28297,28307,28309,28319,28349,28351,28387,28393,28403,28409,28411,28429,28433,28439,28447,28463,28477,28493,28499,28513,28517,28537,28541,28547,28549,28559,28571,28573,28579,28591,28597,28603,28607,28619,28621,28627,28631,28643,28649,28657,28661,28663,28669,28687,28697,28703,28711,28723,28729,28751,28753,28759,28771,28789,28793,28807,28813,28817,28837,28843,28859,28867,28871,28879,28901,28909,28921,28927,28933,28949,28961,28979,29009,29017,29021,29023,29027,29033,29059,29063,29077,29101,29123,29129,29131,29137,29147,29153,29167,29173,29179,29191,29201,29207,29209,29221,29231,29243,29251,29269,29287,29297,29303,29311,29327,29333,29339,29347,29363,29383,29387,29389,29399,29401,29411,29423,29429,29437,29443,29453,29473,29483,29501,29527,29531,29537,29567,29569,29573,29581,29587,29599,29611,29629,29633,29641,29663,29669,29671,29683,29717,29723,29741,29753,29759,29761,29789,29803,29819,29833,29837,29851,29863,29867,29873,29879,29881,29917,29921,29927,29947,29959,29983,29989,30011,30013,30029,30047,30059,30071,30089,30091,30097,30103,30109,30113,30119,30133,30137,30139,30161,30169,30181,30187,30197,30203,30211,30223,30241,30253,30259,30269,30271,30293,30307,30313,30319,30323,30341,30347,30367,30389,30391,30403,30427,30431,30449,30467,30469,30491,30493,30497,30509,30517,30529,30539,30553,30557,30559,30577,30593,30631,30637,30643,30649,30661,30671,30677,30689,30697,30703,30707,30713,30727,30757,30763,30773,30781,30803,30809,30817,30829,30839,30841,30851,30853,30859,30869,30871,30881,30893,30911,30931,30937,30941,30949,30971,30977,30983,31013,31019,31033,31039,31051,31063,31069,31079,31081,31091,31121,31123,31139,31147,31151,31153,31159,31177,31181,31183,31189,31193,31219,31223,31231,31237,31247,31249,31253,31259,31267,31271,31277,31307,31319,31321,31327,31333,31337,31357,31379,31387,31391,31393,31397,31469,31477,31481,31489,31511,31513,31517,31531,31541,31543,31547,31567,31573,31583,31601,31607,31627,31643,31649,31657,31663,31667,31687,31699,31721,31723,31727,31729,31741,31751,31769,31771,31793,31799,31817,31847,31849,31859,31873,31883,31891,31907,31957,31963,31973,31981,31991,32003,32009,32027,32029,32051,32057,32059,32063,32069,32077,32083,32089,32099,32117};

int main()
{
    int test, flag, sq;
    long long int first, second, first_l, secd_l;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    while(test--)
    {
    scanf("%lld",&first);
    scanf("%lld",&second);
    if(first == 1)
        first++;
    if(first == 2 && second != 1)
        printf("%d\n",2);
    first += (first % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0 ;
    for(first_l = first; first_l <= second; first_l += 2)
    {
        flag = 0;
        sq = sqrt(first_l);
        for(secd_l = 0; sq >= prm[secd_l]; secd_l++)
        {
        if(first_l % prm[secd_l] == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        }
        if(flag == 0)
        {
        printf("%lld\n",first_l);
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is another program which is very similar to the first one but using `unsigned int` instead of `long long int`. The execution time I got for this is 2.78s on codechef for same test cases.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int prm[] ={same as before(max character limit in question)};

int main()
{
    int test, flag, sq;
    unsigned int first, second, first_l, secd_l;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    while(test--)
    {
    scanf("%u",&first);
    scanf("%u",&second);
    if(first == 1)
        first++;
    if(first == 2 && second != 1)
        printf("%d\n",2);
    first += (first % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0 ;
    for(first_l = first; first_l <= second; first_l += 2)
    {
        flag = 0;
        sq = sqrt(first_l);
        for(secd_l = 0; sq >= prm[secd_l]; secd_l++)
        {
        if(first_l % prm[secd_l] == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        }
        if(flag == 0)
        {
        printf("%u\n",first_l);
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In another program code I simply used `int` instead of `long long int`/`unsigned int` on the same test cases & I got 2.57 sec execution time.

So, I would like to know why does having `long long int` or `unsigned int` make such a huge difference for my execution time. All the solutions are tested on equal PIII 733 MHZ processors on codechef.

The input format is

> The first line contains t, the number of test cases (less then or equal to 10).
>   Followed by t lines which contain two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> The program is to generate prime numbers between two numbers n & m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are many factors that determine the execution time.

- If you are on a 32bit machine; doing math operation with a type that is 32bits long will take less time than operations on a type that is 64 bits. (uint is probably 32bit, long long int is probably 64bits)
- its is more performant to add variables of the same type (because then no type casting is required)
- depending on how you write your code, the compiler might optimize the code in a different way (but since you only changed the variable type that does not apply here)
- ...

these are just a few ideas; code optimisation is a vast topic :)

Comment: so basically you are saying that the machine used to test our code runs on 32bit that's why it takes almost double time. Also int ranges to 65535 so int code on codechef machine was accepted because test cases didn't contain number larger than this?

Comment: the reason is not that the machine is 32 bit (although the difference in computation time might be less on a 64bit machine)... the difference is caused by the fact that a bigger type requires more CPU cycles to do its calculations...

Comment: and - as @janturon notes; if you are on 32bit machine and you decide to use 64bit variable; you need two registers --> much slower

Answer (score 4):

As Chris Maes points out, on 32bit machines 32bits operations take less time than 64bits. The reason is you need two 32bit registers (usually `EDX` and `EAX` on x86, ALU computes with integers) to work with them or just to display them - this requires more isntructions and more CPU cycles, so it is slower to work with long long (which is probably 64bit) than with int (probably 32bit). Probably, because it is platform dependent, as Gopi points out.

On 64bit machines, there are 64bit registers (like `RAX`) disposable to ALU unit, so in theory it could be faster there. However even on 64bit machine you can perform 32bit computing logic.

Comment: int ranges to 65535.So my int code on codechef machine was accepted because test cases didn't contain number larger than this?

Comment: It ranges **at least** to 65536 (16bits) ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)), on x86 it is usually 32bits, on x64 even 64bits. I don't know about codechef code acceptance, but in C the size is defined by **type**, not the value. `long long a = 42` is larger than `int b = 666`

Comment: in 64-bit OSes int is still most probably [remain 32 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) but it can have any sizes >= 16 bits because the standard doesn't specify the upper limit

Answer (score 3):

On a 32-bit computer obviously doing 64-bit math should be slower than 32-bit ones. Think about how slower you multiply two 2-digit numbers in your head than multiplying two 1-digit numbers. [Note that most PCs about 2 decades back run 32 and 64-bit OSes, so int is a 32-bit type whose range is [-2147483648, 2147483647]. Codechef of course [doesn't use DOS anymore](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/list-compilers) so int should be 32 bits, too.

You need **more memory** and **more registers** to store a 64-bit variable. On an architecture that is low on register number like x86, less registers left may incur more memory accesses to spill the values for the other variables. As memory bandwidth is limited, less variables can be read/write at once and less variables fit in cache, too, so that'll be twice slower and if you need to access a lot of memory, *much* slower when a cache miss appears

You also need **more instructions** to process values larger than the register size. To add/subtract 2 64-bit values on x86 you need 2 instructions

```
add edx, ebx  // add low part
adc eax, ecx  // add high part with carry
```

Each instruction above adds 2 32-bit registers, so you can see that you only need 1 instruction to add two 32-bit `int`s

For more complex operations like multiplication and division the difference in performance would be much larger. You can see that gcc generates **a lot** of instructions to multiply a 32-bit number by a 64-bit one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11680720/995714). Your program has a modulo operation so the compiler might need to emit a division, which is the most complex in 4 basic operations. Therefore the performance is even worse.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-operations-in-int-faster-than-long-long-int/answer/L%C6%B0u-V%C4%A9nh-Ph%C3%BAc?srid=teex)

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)
```

So in order to access more bytes in long the time taken will be more. Though the sizeof data-types is completely platform dependent. The point here is in order to access 64 bits more CPU cycles is needed than accessing 32 bits on a 32bit machine.

Comment: CPUs nowadays have bandwidth of at least 64 bits so reading 32 or 64-bit values takes the same time unless you're reading a lot of memory, like an array, at once