# Unsure about cmp/jg behavior in AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, x86, att

I have some assembly code that is not behaving as expected, specifically these lines:

```
cmp $0x5, %eax
jg
```

I am stepping through gdb, and putting a breakpoint on the line with cmp.
At that point in time, eax holds the value `0x1`

Thus, 0x5 is greater than 0x1, so it should be taking the jump.  However the code does not take the jump.

Am I missing something easy here?

Comment: Well, where do you expect it to jump? Shouldn't you give the destination address to `jg`?

Comment: The comparison conditionals are to be inserted between `cmp` operands when those operands are written in Intel syntax, so `cmp eax, 5` will branch on `jg` if `eax` is greater-than 5. Refer to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397528/mov-src-dest-or-mov-dest-src/60596999#60596999

Comment: Duplicate of [What does JL mean in at&t syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26982366)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion is caused by that &#^?%*$! AT&T syntax :)

In Intel's own syntax it would be

```
cmp eax, 5
jg
```

which (IMHO) makes it much more obvious that the jump is taken if the value of eax is greater than 5.

Comment: To think in AT&T syntax, read right to left: `cmp $5, %eax` / `jg` is jump if EAX is greater than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation. The Intel syntax is clearer: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow