# What does JL mean in at&t syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm working on a project for school and I cannot find anything on the what `JL` means in at&t syntax. For reference, the question is to find the value of `%eax` when `NOP` runs. Here is the code it's used in:

```
MOV $492,%ebx
MOV $2494,%eax
MOV $28063,%ecx
CMP %eax,%ebx
JL L1
JMP L2
L1:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
ADD %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
SUB %ecx,%eax
JMP L3
L2:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
SUB %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
ADD %ecx,%eax
L3:
NOP
```

Also I would appreciate what `JMP` does as well as how the addition/subtraction/multiplication works (`ADD`/`SUB`/`IMUL`). I don't want to cheat, I just want to understand what's happening. For example, do you change the first number or the second when using math? Thank you all so much for helping.

Comment: Jump if Less than? It's not so much the AT&T syntax here as the x86 instruction set.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: AT&T syntax does matter, because the operands are switched in AT&T syntax!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

That is assemply language , `JL` is `Jump if Less`

This also works in x86 assembly language.

```
 CMP %eax,%ebx 
 JL L1
```

We compare EAX to EBX, then we'll jump to L1 depending on that comparison.

More specific - If the contents of EAX are less than the contents of EBX, jump to the label L1

See -        [Assembly - JG/JNLE/JL/JNGE after CMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617877/assembly-jg-jnle-jl-jnge-after-cmp)

Comment: That makes sense, but how does it jump is %eax is more or if %ebx is more?

Comment: Will it jump to L1 if %eax is more or if %ebx is more?

Comment: @Ella  - we say "less than the contents of EBX,"  means , EBX right ?

Comment: @Ella - It's been a while for me, since I touched ASM

Comment: @Coffee: Now that I have enough reputation to write a comment: Could you please correct your sentence "More specific - If the contents of EAX are less than the contents of EBX, jump to the label L1"? In AT&T syntax it is exactly the other way round, and OP explicitly asked for AT&T syntax. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 13):

In [AT&T syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info), the operands are [in the opposite order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397528/mov-src-dest-or-mov-dest-src/60596999#60596999) vs. Intel syntax.  So when looking at the `cmp`, you should read right to left for the mnemonic to match up with the meaning.

```
CMP %eax,%ebx
JL L1
```

That code interpreted in AT&T syntax: "If the contents of EBX are less than the contents of EAX, jump to the label L1".

(An older accepted answer got this wrong.)

*[Assembly - JG/JNLE/JL/JNGE after CMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617877/assembly-jg-jnle-jl-jnge-after-cmp)* explains all of x86's FLAGS conditions you can branch on (or setcc or cmovcc).  That Q&A uses Intel syntax, where reading `cmp` operands left-to-right corresponds to the semantic meaning of the conditions.  (See also an [HTML scrape of Intel's actual PDF manual for `jcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc), and further docs linked in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info))

Answer (score 1):

jl (jump on less than, signed)
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language)