# How does conditional jump of x86-64 works?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att, conditional-execution

I'm so confused about conditional branch while I was studying x86-64.

```
compq %rax,%rdi
jl .L2
```

Which one is the correct understanding?

1. if %rax < %rdi, jump to L2
2. if %rax > %rdi, jump to L2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `compq` in x86-64. There's [CMP](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html) which will be `cmpq` when comparing 64-bit operands in AT&T syntax.

It'll be clearer when using Intel syntax, because AT&T swaps the destination and source which will be [more confusing on instructions like `cmp` and `sub`](http://x86asm.net/articles/what-i-dislike-about-gas/)

```
cmp rdi, rax
jl .L2
```

[Jcc instructions](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) always compare the first operand with the second one. In this case it'll jump when rdi < rax

- [What does JL mean in at&t syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26982366/995714)

Comment: This will jump when `(long int)rax < (long int)rdi`.