# The difference between cmpl and cmp

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att, instructions

I am trying to understand assembly to be able to solve a puzzle. However I encountered the following instructions:

```
0x0000000000401136 <+44>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x14(%rsp)
0x000000000040113b <+49>:    ja     0x401230 <phase_3+294>
```

What I think it's doing is:
The value of `0x14(%rsp)` is -7380. According to my understanding `cmpl` compares unsigned. Also the jump is performed.

So can it be that `(unsigned)-7380 > 7` --> jump

I actually don't want it to jump. But is this the correct explanation or not? Am I flipping arguments?

Also if you have any advice about how to manipulate this jump!

Comment: *l* in cmpl is to specify 32-bit memory argument. *a* part of ja is to specify signed/unsigned. Look up on branch instructions.

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention (and tag) what processor architecture this refers to.

Comment: it's just the AT&T syntax's size suffix

Comment: @phuclv: The question isn't specific to x86-64; 32-bit disassembly can also contain `cmpl`.  I re-added the `x86` tag (along with AT&T, which this question *is* specific to.  Well I guess goasm syntax for x86 also uses operand-size suffixes...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> According to my understanding `cmpl` compares unsigned.

It does both, in a way.

The difference in signed vs. unsigned is here the usage of the jump instructions.

For `>`, there is `ja` for unsigned and `jg` for signed (jump if above and jump if greater).

For `<`, there is `jb` for unsigned and `jl` for signed (jump if below and jump if less).

To be exact, here is the meaning of several jump commands:

> For unsigned comparisons:
>
> ```
> JB/JNAE (CF = 1)           : Jump if below/not above or equal
> JAE/JNB (CF = 0)           : Jump if above or equal/not below
> JBE/JNA (CF = 1 or ZF = 1) : Jump if below or equal/not above
> JA/JNBE (CF = 0 and ZF = 0): Jump if above/not below or equal
> ```
>
> For signed comparisons:
>
> ```
> JL/JNGE (SF <> OF)          : Jump if less/not greater or equal
> JGE/JNL (SF = OF)           : Jump if greater or equal/not less
> JLE/JNG (ZF = 1 or SF <> OF): Jump if less or equal/not greater
> JG/JNLE (ZF = 0 and SF = OF): Jump if greater/not less or equal
> ```

Comment: Above/below are for unsigned

Comment: @MicroVirus Thx, added a bit of detail

Comment: In short: G(reater) and L(ess) are for signed, while A(bove) and B(elow) are for unsigned comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add one extra detail for clarification to @glglgl's excellent answer is that the "l" in "cmpl" is an [operation suffix](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) indicating that the operation is being done on a long number (32 bit integer or 64-bit floating point).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think x86 actually has an instruction called `CMPL`. It's probably part of your assembler syntax to give hints on operands or something else (like `JZ` and `JE` being the same).

From the intel manual on what it is doing:

> Compares the first source operand with the second source operand and sets the 
>   status flags in the EFLAGS register according to the results. The comparison is 
>   performed by subtracting the second operand from the first operand and then setting 
>   the status flags in the same manner as the SUB instruction. When an immediate 
>   value is used as an operand, it is sign-extended to the length of the first operand.

Sign-ness is given implicitly, because of the two's complement representation of numbers.

How to manipulate the jump? If you are sure that the jump should do the exact opposite than what it is doing, you just have to change `JA` to `JBE`.

Comment: That Intel manual quote is misleading: AT&T syntax reverses the order of the operand list.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397528/mov-src-dest-or-mov-dest-src/60596999#60596999