# C functions compiled into assembly code

Tags: c, assembly

I´m learning assembly at school and I´m wondering if I´m understanding it right.  If I have 3 C code functions

```
int fun1(int a, int b)
{
unsigned ua = (unsigned) a;
if (ua < b)
return b;
else
return ua;
}

int fun2(int a, int b)
{
if (b < a)
return b;
else
return a;
}

int fun3(int a, int b)
{
if (a < b)
return a;
else
return b;
}
```

And then I have the assembly code

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
movl 8(%ebp),%edx
movl 12(%ebp),%eax
cmpl %eax,%edx
jge .L3
movl %edx,%eax
.L3:
movl %ebp,%esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Am I understanding it right that fun1 is the right C code for the assembly code?

That is first 2 lines are the head, next two adds int a and int b into their "spot", cmpl is the unsigned ua = (unsigned) a and then if ua is not bigger or equal as b then we jump straight to .L3.

Or I´m I thinking it all wrong?

Comment: Your classmate has already asked that same question 4 days ago here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188068/assembly-language-how-it-works/26191257#26191257



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188068/assembly-language-how-it-works/26191257#26191257

Answer (score 2):

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
```

this is the head

```
movl 8(%ebp),%edx
movl 12(%ebp),%eax
```

this takes a and b into registers

```
cmpl %eax,%edx
```

this is the condition

```
movl %edx,%eax
.L3:
movl %ebp,%esp
```

and this is the result of condition

```
popl %ebp
ret
```

ending