# Regarding cmp / jg, jle, etc in AT&T syntax assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

So every single resource online tells me that something like this:

```
cmp %eax, %ebx
jg < something >
```

would jump to < something > if eax was greater than ebx. But I have another piece of code that seems to contradict this:

```
cmp $0x2, %eax
jg  < something>
```

as it jumps to < something > when eax has the value 3.

Am I missing something, or does cmp a, b - jg execute if b > a and not a>b? And does this apply to other jump statements as well?

Comment: Looks like AT&T syntax, it puts the operands in the wrong order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we read something like

```
cmp $0x2, %eax
jg  < something >
```

we know the assembler used is one that reverses the position of the operands of an instruction. That's because Intel's syntax dictates that the destination operand comes before the source operand and clearly an immediate value like $0x2 can't ever be a destination!

Knowing the order of things we now interpret your first code snippet as

```
cmp ebx, eax
jg < something >  ;jump if EBX > EAX
```

and the second code snippet as

```
cmp eax, 2
jg < something >  ;jump if EAX > 2
```

> And does this apply to other jump statements as well?

It does.

Comment: Incidentally, the leading % signs on the register names are also a giveaway, I've never seen an "Intel convention" (destination, source) assembler use those.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that `jg` jumps if the destination operand is greater-than the source.  For AT&T that means it's checking if `$2 < %eax`, reading right to left.

Answer (score 1):

See if **[THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188068/assembly-language-how-it-works/26191257#26191257)** helps you.  If not, ask for clarification.

Scroll down past the other guy's source code and stuff in that answer to search for this string...

**This biz, the cmpl %eax,%edx instruction, is one of the forms of the "compare" instructions**

I wrote an explanation of the "sense" of `CMP` and various conditional jumps. See if it answers your questions here.

If you are still confused, post a note here and someone else may give you a better answer.

Hope it helps.