# Assembly: suggested way on jumping into and out of a label (similar to a C if statement)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, att

I am writing an assembly loop to get the max number in an array. It loops like this:

```
start_loop:

    # Get the current element in the array and move it to %rax
    # movz --> (1) b(yte-1), w(ord-2), l(long-4), q(uad-8)
    movzwq data_items(,%rdi,2), %rax

    # Check if the current element value is zero, if it is, jump to the end
    cmp $0, %rax
    jz exit

    # Increment the array index as we want to continue the loop at the end
    inc %rdi

    # Compare the current value (rax) to the current max (rbx)
    # WARNING: The `cmp` instruction is always backwards with ATT syntax!
    # It reads as, "With respect to %rbx, the value of %rax is...(greater|less) than"
    # So to see if a > b, do:
    #   cmp b, a
    #   jg
    # Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26191257/12283168
    cmp %rbx, %rax
    jge update_value

    jmp start_loop


update_value:
    mov %rax, %rbx
    jmp start_loop


exit:
    mov $1, %rax           
    int $0x80
```

My question is this part of the comparison code here:

```
    jge update_value
    jmp start_loop

update_value:
    mov %rax, %rbx
    jmp start_loop # <== can I get rid of this part?
```

Is there a way to not have to specify the `jmp start_loop` in the update_value section? For example, in a high level language I could do:

```
while (1) {
    if (a > b)
        update_value();
    // continue
}
```

And not have to "jump back to `while` from the update_value function, I could just 'continue'. Is it possible to do something like this in assembly, or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: What you _can_ do is replace `jge update_value` `jmp start_loop`  with `jl start_loop`.

Comment: Yeah, use `jl start_loop` like a normal person to implement the `else continue`.  "continue" is equivalent to jumping to the top of the loop.  In general, never `jcc` over a `jmp` alone, just write the opposite condition to either jump where you want or fall through (e.g. out of a loop).  Asm doesn't have scopes or structure, it's up to you to implement those concepts.  See also [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)

Comment: @PeterCordes can you please clarify what you mean by: "In general, never `jcc` over a `jmp` alone" ?

Comment: Look at `clang -O2` or `gcc -O2` output for examples of how to lay out loop / branch structure.  Sometimes it's more complicated than a skilled human would make it, but you can learn a lot by understanding how their choices work.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: @PeterCordes it seems like they use `call` a lot too rather than `jmp`.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: JCC is any conditional branch (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc).  Never lay out your code with `jcc x` / jmp somewhere` / `x:` so the only instruction being jumped over is a JMP.  When execution enters these 2 instructions, it always either jumps somewhere or comes out the other side.  But you can do the same thing with `jcc somewhere` with the opposite condition.  Intel even has synonyms for negative conditions, like `jnge start_loop` is the same instruction as `jl start_loop`.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: Yes, of course compilers use `call` for functions, if they don't inline them.  Enable full optimization to get inlining.  `jcc` over a `call` is the only good way to do a conditional *call*, but if you don't want to call/ret, instead just jump around between labels without leaving breadcrumbs (return addresses) on the stack, that code is either part of one big function.

Comment: (Making optimized tailcalls is also done with jmp or jcc, but a single loop and some ifs would normally be considered one function.  Of course asm makes it possible to write true spaghetti code if you don't have some high-level structure in mind as you write, where the whole program is a mess of interlocking blocks.)

Comment: @PeterCordes so a better pattern would be to do: `cmp %rbx, %rax; jl start_loop; mov %rax, %rbx; jmp start_loop` ?

Comment: @Michael what about after the `jl` though?

Comment: Yes, except that the opposite of `jge` is `jl`.  However, to implement your C logic of `if(a>b) update()`, you should have used `jg` over jmp (bad) or `jle` to the top (good).  Oh, I just noticed you're writing `update_value()` *as a function* in C.  Not as `max_seen = a`

Comment: Note that a label doesn't hold anything.  It's just an annotation marking a location in your program.  You cannot jump “into and out of a label,” because there is no “inside a label.”  Make sure you don't have any misconceptions here!

Comment: Since your `update_value` is just a `mov`, you could replace everything between the `cmp` and the final `jmp start_loop` with a `cmovge`. But whether that would be more efficient depends on what your array contains (which in turn determines how well your conditional branch can be predicted).