# Assembly - store the result of a comparison (1 if true, 0 if false)?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm writing a compiler for a uni assignment, I'm currently emitting asm from an internal representation. I have the following representation for `for (a = 1; a < 10; a++) do print a`:

```
COPY a, 1                    // Copy 1 to a
LABEL label0                 // 
LT tmp0, a, 10               // Store in tmp0 the result of the expression a < 10
JUMP_FALSE label1, tmp0      // Jump to label1 if tmp0 is false
PRINT a                      //
ADD a, a, 1                  // Store in a the result of the expression a + 1
JUMP label0                  //
LABEL label1                 //
```

I am emitting the following asm for this, where both constants and variables are emitted as globals variables for orthogonality:

```
#a := 1
movl var_1(%rip), %eax
movl %eax, var_a(%rip)
.label0:
#EXPR_START tmp0 = a < 10
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl var_10(%rip), %edx
cmpl %eax, %edx
setl %al
movzbl %al, %eax
movl %eax, var_tmp0(%rip)
#EXPR_END
#jmpf label1, tmp0
movl var_tmp0(%rip), %eax
testl %eax, %eax
jne .label1
#Print a
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl %eax, %esi
leaq printf_int(%rip), %rdi
movl $0, %eax
call printf@PLT
movl $0, %eax
#EXPR_START a = a + 1
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl var_1(%rip), %edx
addl %edx, %eax
movl %eax, var_a(%rip)
#EXPR_END
#jmp label0
jmp .label0
.label1:
```

This seems to be comparing `a <= 10`, but I don't understand why. Isn't the `cmpl` and `setl` combo setting the value of `%al` as 1 if the result of the comparison was "less then"? Then shouldn't `testl %eax, %eax` be `1` while `a < 10` and `jne` occur when `a == 10`? If my understanding is wrong, **how can I store the result of a comparison in a register (1 if the comparison holds, 0 otherwise)?**

Below is the full asm which can be compiled with `gcc asm.s`. The expected output is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` the actual output is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

```
main:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
#a := 1
movl var_1(%rip), %eax
movl %eax, var_a(%rip)
.label0:
#EXPR_START
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl var_10(%rip), %edx
cmpl %eax, %edx
setl %al
movzbl %al, %eax
movl %eax, var_tmp0(%rip)
#EXPR_END
#jmpf label1, tmp0
movl var_tmp0(%rip), %eax
movl $1, %edx
cmpl %eax, %edx
je .label1
#Print a
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl %eax, %esi
leaq _printf_int(%rip), %rdi
movl $0, %eax
call printf@PLT
movl $0, %eax
#EXPR_START
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl var_1(%rip), %edx
addl %edx, %eax
movl %eax, var_a(%rip)
#EXPR_END
#jmp label0
jmp .label0
.label1:
popq %rbp
ret
.text
.globl var_tmp1
.data
.size var_tmp1, 4
var_tmp1:
.long 0
.text
.globl main
.text
.globl var_1
.data
.size var_1, 4
var_1:
.long 1
.text
.globl var_a
.data
.size var_a, 4
var_a:
.long 0
.text
.globl var_10
.data
.size var_10, 4
var_10:
.long 10
.text
.globl var_tmp0
.data
.size var_tmp0, 4
var_tmp0:
.long 0
_printf_int:
.string "%d "
```

Comment: You have coded `if (10 < a) goto label1`. You have swapped the operand order in the `cmp` and you have used `if (tmp0 == 1)` meaning `JUMP_TRUE` not `JUMP_FALSE`.

Answer (score 4):

```
movl var_a(%rip), %eax
movl var_10(%rip), %edx
cmpl %eax, %edx
setl %al
```

This will set `%al` to 1 if `%edx` is less than `%eax`, i.e. if 10 is less than `a`. That seems to be the opposite of what you wanted, so either interchange the operands of `cmpl` or else reverse your test (`setge %al`).

Part of the confusion may come from the fact that the assembler mnemonics were originally invented for Intel syntax, in which the source and destination for two-operand instructions are in the other order: `mov dest, src` instead of AT&T's `movl %src, %dest`.  So in Intel syntax, `cmp rx, ry ; setl rz` would set `rz` if `rx` is less than `ry`, which matches the algebraic notation `rx < ry`.  But for AT&T syntax this becomes `cmpl %ry, %rx ; setl %rz` which may look backwards.  It may help to think of the second, "destination" operand as being the one that the predicate is "about": "set if `%rx` is less than `%ry`".

Comment: Related answer about the condition order mismatch in AT&T syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397528/mov-src-dest-or-mov-dest-src/60596999#60596999